# Reusing Lucene Query objects

Tags: java, performance, lucene

Are Lucene's `Query` objects reusable/stateless ?

If not, will `clone()`ing a `TermQuery` be faster than rebuilding it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes: [The purpose of Weight is to ensure searching does not modify a Query, so that a Query instance can be reused.](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Weight.html)